# how to add if statement in tabular format in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

after ajax response, how can I add if statement inside each column ?

```
 bodyData+='<tr id="row_'+i+'" >'
          bodyData+='<td >'+ i +"</td><td>"+row.created_format+"</td><td>"+row.email+"</td>;
```

thanks

Comment: where you need to add `if-else` ?can you elaborate more? with response also which you got from server ?

Comment: i want to add inside one of the columns, I get a response from the server,```"</td><td>" if(row.email !=null){ +row.email+ }else{ " empty" }``` itry not workin

Comment: guys, i just ask where to put if in jquery, that is all the format condition only, b/c +"<td><td>"++" confusing me

Comment: @ShowMore does my answer resolve your issue? If yes, please mark it as the answer, if not please modify your question for us to better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from reading the comments you want something that checks to see if the value is null inline. You can use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for this or the [null coalesce](https://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/10/14/javascript-gem-null-coalescing-using-the-or-operator).

```js
let bodyData = '';
let row = {'created_format': 'value', 'email': null}
let i = undefined;
bodyData+='<tr id="row_'+(i || 'empty')+'" >'; //Null coalesce used
bodyData+='<td >'+ i +'</td><td>'+(row.created_format != null ? row.created_format : 'empty')+'</td><td>'+row.email+'</td>'; //ternary operator used
console.log(bodyData);
```